# Implement rotate on react-leaflet rectangles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, leaflet, rotation

My goal is to make the rectangles on the leaflet map rotate. This map is for a concert with a lot of seats and some of them will need to rotated to fit the map photo.

After a lot of research i found that the "leaflet-path-transform" library are able to solve this problem, but i have not been able to make this work.

Can someone help me to make this work?
When i read the docs i cant see how it should work because of the leaflet code is not close to mine at all.

This is a child component that is rendered in a leaflet map.

```
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-path-transform";
import { Marker, Rectangle } from "react-leaflet";
import { BookableResource } from "../../common/model/models";

export default function EditRectangleWithLabel({
  label,
  rectangle,
  activeResource,
  setActiveResource,
}: {
  label: string;
  rectangle: BookableResource;
  activeResource: number;
  setActiveResource: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}) {
  const center = L.rectangle(rectangle.placement!.bounds)
    .getBounds()
    .getCenter();

  const text = L.divIcon({ html: label });
  text.options.className = "text-secondary text-center font-bold font-roboto";

  return rectangle.placement ? (
    <Rectangle
      key={rectangle.resourceId + "-rectangle"}
      bounds={rectangle.placement.bounds}
      pathOptions={{
        color: "#008959",
        fillColor: "white",
        fillOpacity:
          activeResource && activeResource !== rectangle.resourceId ? 0.5 : 0.9,
        opacity:
          activeResource && activeResource !== rectangle.resourceId ? 0.2 : 1,
      }}
      eventHandlers={{ click: () => setActiveResource(rectangle.resourceId) }}
      /* transform={true} */
    >
      <Marker
        key={rectangle.resourceId}
        position={center}
        icon={text}
        eventHandlers={{ click: () => setActiveResource(rectangle.resourceId) }}
      />
    </Rectangle>
  ) : null;
}
```

I have tried everything and i also get problems because of the library is not typescript supported.